# latest vs code - simple console app to ask for number

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have a simple console app that asks the user for 2 numbers. However, when I try to run it I'm not getting the prompts?  This seems so simple?

I've tried both

```
dotnet new console
dotnet new console --use-program-main


// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.Write("First number? ");
var number1 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Second number? ");
var number2 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
```

[image]

[image]

When I use cmd line and goto bin and execute it there it behaves as expected.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Code is text, and should be copied and pasted directly into your question.

Comment: The code is present as text as well. I think the images are only conveying the console behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug console (which is what you are selected on in your screenshot) doesn't accept any kind of input for a running program.

According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-7-0):

> The **Debug Console** doesn't accept terminal input for a running program. To handle terminal input while debugging, you can use the integrated terminal (one of the Visual Studio Code windows) or an external terminal.

As this states, you need to use the integrated terminal is Visual Studio Code, or an external one.  The documentation also states how to do this.  To summarize:

1. Open your launch.json file used for debugging.
2. Change the `console` property to be either `integratedTerminal` or `externalTerminal`.

If you opt to use the integrated terminal, when you debug, switch to the "Terminal" tab, and you'll see your prompts:

[image: terminal tab showing first number prompt]